# que esta mal con este path que me trae la ruta doble?

Tags: java, rutas

Obtengo una ruta relativa de esta manera

```
  String path = getClass().getResource("/META-INF/persistence.xml").toString();
```

y me arroja esta excepcion:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Priojects\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication6\file:\C:\Users\Priojects\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication6\build\classes\META-INF\persistence.xml
>   (El nombre de archivo, el nombre de directorio o la sintaxis de la
>   etiqueta del volumen no son correctos)

la excepcion muestra dos rutas una de C:.... hasta file (no se de donde sale este file) y la otra a partir de file:

> \C:\Users\Priojects\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication6\build\classes\META-INF\persistence.xml

(esta es la correcta)
quiero que solo me aparezca la correcta. Agradezco mucho su ayuda

Comment: Sebastian, me parece un poco raro el problema que comentas, opino que puedes estar concatenando  el segundo path posteriormente a obtener la ruta de "/META-INF/persistence.xml", que obtienes al obtener String path = getClass().getResource("/META-INF/persistence.xml").toString(); , cual es el valor de path?

Comment: Si vas a usar el archivo para algo puedes hacer esto: `File file = new File("classes/META-INF/persistence.xml");
String strPath = file.getAbsolutePath();`